# How can I select a xml element based on some attribute and write it back complete in another file

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I'm reading an svg/xml with `XmlTextReader` and I want to write just some of its elements back in a new svg/xml file

```
<svg>
    <rect x="135.7" y="537.4" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2894" width="36.6" height="42.2"/>
    <rect x="99" y="537.4" fill="#A0C9EC" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2894" width="36.7" height="42.2"/>
</svg>
```

I want the rect elements that are filled with "none" so I started reading and writing

```
 var reader = new XmlTextReader(file.InputStream);
 var writer = new XmlTextWriter(svgPath + fileNameWithoutExtension + "-less" + extension, null);
 writer.WriteStartDocument();
 while (reader.Read())
 {
    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
         case XmlNodeType.Element:
         if (reader.Name == "svg")
         {
            writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
            while(reader.MoveToNextAttribute()){
                 writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
            }
         }
         if (reader.Name == "rect" || reader.Name == "polygon")
         {
            while(reader.MoveToNextAttribute()){
                 if(reader.Name == "fill" && reader.value == "none"){
                     writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                     writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                     writer.WriteEndElement();
                 }
            }
         }
         break;
         case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
              break;

         default:
              break;
    }
 }
 writer.WriteEndElement();
 writer.WriteEndDocument();
 writer.Close();
```

but that returns a file with "fill" elements and no "x" and "y" attributes (because the `WriteAttributes` read from the current position and the reader is in the fill attribute)

```
 <svg>
     <fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2894" width="36.6" height="42.2"/>
 </svg>
```

Is there a way to get the result I want? I don't want to use `XmlDocument` since my svg files are large and take a long time to load with `XmlDoc.Load`

Thanks

Comment: is there a particular reason why you want to use XmlTextReader and XmlTextWriter? or you just looking to manipulate some xml?

Comment: I tried with xmlDocument but load is much slower and with XmlTextReader it seems to end sooner

Comment: When you check reader.Name == "rect", you could try string fill = reader.GetAttribute("fill") and then proceed from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following; you can adapt to suit:

```
     if (reader.Name == "rect" || reader.Name == "polygon") 
     { 
           string fill = reader.GetAttribute("fill"); //Read ahead for the value of the fill attr
           if(String.Compare(fill, "none", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0) //if the value is what we expect then just wholesale copy this node.
           {
                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true); 
                writer.WriteEndElement(); 
            } 
        }
```

Note that [GetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxy2cd1w.aspx) does not move the reader, allowing you to stay in the context of the rect or polygon node.

You could probably also try revising your first attempt with a single reader.MoveToFirstAttribute() - I haven't tested that but it should move you back to the first element of the current node.

You might also want to investigate the XPathDocument class - this is a lot lighter than XmlDocument but you still load the entire structure into memory first so may not be suitable - selecting the nodes you want would then simply be a case of using the XPath:

```
//rect[@fill='none'] || //polygon[@fill='none']
```

Finally, you could also use an XSLT. If you wanted to post a more complete structure for your source document I'd be happy to write one for you.

Comment: exactly what I wanted, thanks, I will try the XSLT option later

Comment: In .Net, using the XmlReader is probably the most efficient way - unfortunately, as .Net only implements XSLT 1.0 it has to load the whole document tree into memory for the XslTransform method. If Microsoft ever get round to implementing XSLT 3.0 this will change as it allows for streaming transformations. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is nasty business using imperative C#, you might consider using XSLT instead:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_value-of.asp

Comment: You are right it looks nasty I'm goint to investigate about XSLT Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to store reader.Name in a variable before you call MoveToNextAttribute. Then when you call WriteStartElement, use that value instead.

```
if (reader.Name == "rect" || reader.Name == "polygon")
{
    // get tag name here
    var tagName = reader.Name;

    while(reader.MoveToNextAttribute()){
        if(reader.Name == "fill" && reader.value == "none"){

            // write tag name here
            writer.WriteStartElement(tagName);

            writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's right but then I lost the first two attributes "x" and "y"